# How to restart my game once the user has quit(Libgdx)

Tags: java, libgdx

In my libgdx game it functions how i want it to but when i exit the game it starts of from where i was before, i want it to restart. The code is as follows.

```
package com.me.fixGame;

import java.util.Random;









import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;


import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
//import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Scaling;
import com.sun.jmx.snmp.tasks.Task;


public class fixGame implements ApplicationListener {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture trash; 
    Texture paper;
    SpriteBatch spritebatch;
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 pas;
    boolean collide;
    boolean countMe=false;
    Vector2 size;
    Vector2 size2;
    Vector2 pos;
    Rectangle bounds;
    float posSpeed=30;
    Rectangle bounds2;
    float delay = 1; // seconds
boolean counted= false;
    int score = 3;
    //Texture Gogreen;
    String myScore;
    Texture background; 
    CharSequence str = "Lives left: 3"; // = myScore;
    CharSequence line = "Score: 0"; // = myScore;
    String myLife;
    int life=0;
    BitmapFont font;
    float x;
    float y;
    boolean collision = false;
    @Override
    public void create() {  

     //Gogreen = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/gogreenNow.jpg"));
     background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/trash.png"));

     x= background.getWidth();
     y=background.getHeight();
        //float delaySeconds = 1;
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    trash = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/trash.png"));
    paper = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/paper1.jpg"));
    position = new Vector2(100, 50);
    pos = new Vector2(54, 14);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();

    size2 = new Vector2(trash.getWidth() ,trash.getHeight() );
    //size2.y = trash.getHeight();
    //size2.x = trash.getWidth();
    size = new Vector2(paper.getWidth() ,paper.getHeight());

    bounds= new Rectangle(pos.x, pos.y, size.x, size.y);
    bounds2= new Rectangle(position.x, position.y, size2.x, size2.y);

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
    public void update(){
        bounds.set(pos.x, pos.y, size.x, size.y);
        bounds2.set(position.x, position.y, size2.x, size2.y);
        float pos1=Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
        //if(pos1<0)
        //  pos1=(-1)*pos1;
        position.x = position.x - 5*pos1;
    }




    @Override
    public void render() {
        if(bounds.overlaps(bounds2)){
            collision=true; 
            counted=true;
        }else{
            collision=false;
        }

        if(collision==true){

        } 
        if(pos.y<640){
            counted=false;
        } else if(pos.y > 640 && collision==false && counted==false){
            counted=true;
            score= score-1;
            myScore = "Lives left: " + score;
            str = myScore;
        }



        if(bounds.overlaps(bounds2)){

            countMe=true;
            life= life+50;
            myLife = "Score: " + life;
            line = myLife;
        }


        if(position.x<0){
            position.x= position.x+11;
        }
        if(position.x>425){
            position.x= position.x-11;
        }


          update();
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        pos.y=pos.y-posSpeed;
        //posSpeed = posSpeed+(2/3);
        if(pos.y<0){
            pos.y = 700;
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
              pos.x = randomGenerator.nextInt(500);
        }
        BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();


        batch.begin();

         batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
         if (!collision) {
                batch.draw(paper, pos.x, pos.y);

                }

        //batch.draw(paper, pos.x, pos.y);
        batch.draw(trash, position.x, position.y);
        font.setScale(3);

        font.setColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f);
        font.draw(batch, str, 300,900);
        font.draw(batch, line, 300, 950);
                batch.end();
                font.dispose();     
    }

     @Override  
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

I searched through out the web and I could not find anything. Does anybody have any answers?
Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: No offense but this is not the approach to code a complex game. Maintain a proper architecture

Comment: Yes, I have worked on it, i did not know about this... I am a sixth grader.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about desktop or Android?

Assuming you're talking about Android, when the user exits the game, the pause() function is called. When the user goes back to the game, the resume() function is called.

I would bet that your game would "reset" if you ran some other apps between exiting and resuming the game. Normally people save the state of the game in pause() and then load it in resume(), but for your case, it sounds like you just want to reset it each time.

If all of the above is actually true for you, just reset the game state in the resume() function.

Answer (score 0):

For Android: If the user presses the "Home" button or a call is incoming the games `pause()` method is called. If the user returns after the call or after some time normally `resume()` is called. But if the Android OS decided to close your app, `create()` will be called, and if you do not store savegames i am sure it would reset the game.
In your case the user did not exit the game but "pause" it by pressing "Home" button. To reset the game then, you could call `dispose()` in your `pause()` method, and in dispose you simply close your app. On Desktop `pause()` is called if you switch window or minimize the app, as far as i know. If you do not want to close the app in this case you have to controll, if it is desktop or android.